# AutoMapper How to select Collection's property, project it into DTO & return projected collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper, projection

Source models:

```cs
public class ExampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public float Something { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; } = "";
}

public class ExampleModelContainer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ExampleModel Model { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class LargeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ExampleModelContainer> ModelEntries { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Target models:

```cs
public class ExampleModelDto
{
    public float Something { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; } = "";
}

public class LargeEntityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ExampleModelDto> Models { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

AutoMapper profile:

```cs
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ExampleModel, ExampleModelDto>();
        
        // One of my attempt, I thought converting container into model, and automatically example model into DTO. Failed
        CreateMap<ExampleModelContainer, ExampleModel>()
            .ConvertUsing(x => x.Model);
        
        CreateMap<LargeEntity, LargeEntityDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Models, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.ModelEntries));
    }
}
```

Expected result:
LargeEntities' `List<ExampleModelContainer>` collection is mapped into `List<ExampleModelDto>`.

Actual result:

```
Unhandled exception. AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: The following member on AutoMapperExps.Models.LargeEntityDto cannot be mapped:
        Models
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type AutoMapperExps.Models.LargeEntityDto.
Context:
        Mapping to member Models from AutoMapperExps.Models.LargeEntity to AutoMapperExps.Models.LargeEntityDto
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationExpressionIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Experiments\AutoMapperExps\Program.cs:line 1
```

How I see it possible to be made:

1. Mapper takes source `List<ExampleModelContainer>` collection
2. Mapper Selects `Model` property from each element of collection
3. Mapper projects ExampleModel (returned from property above) into ExampleModelDto
4. Mapper returns `List<ExampleModelDto>` as a final result.

Note: This is made for Entity Framework queries. I want to do most projection operations on server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: AutoMapper throws the exception because it cannot find a mapping `ExampleModelContainer -> ExampleDto`. If you define a mapping the error is fixed, e.g.:

```
CreateMap<ExampleModelContainer, ExampleModelDto>()
  .IncludeMembers(x => x.Model);
```

---

The mapping tries to take several steps at once. If I understand your sample right, the configured mappings are like this:

```
ExampleModel          -> ExampleDto
ExampleModelContainer -> ExampleModel
LargeEntity           -> LargeEntityDto
```

When mapping the `Models` property in for LargeEntityDto, you are trying to map a `List<ExampleModelContainer>` without further configuration to a `List<ExampleModelDto>`. It may seem clear for AutoMapper to take the route

`ExampleModelContainer -> ExampleModel -> ExampleDto`

in this case, because there is only one path. But what if there were several paths to get from a `ExampleModelContainer` to a `ExampleDto`? The library would not be able to make a decision that solves all possible combinations.

This means that you as a developer have to make the decision by configuring a mapping from `ExampleModelContainer` to `ExampleModelDto`, e.g.:

```
CreateMap<ExampleModelContainer, ExampleModelDto>()
  .IncludeMembers(x => x.Model);
```

This way, AutoMapper has a direct mapping between the types and is able to map the properties. See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y43wyf) to test.

Comment: I have a problem with your answer. I added Id field to the DTO (as I do in my source project, and spotted a problem: When I ran this code: https://paste.mod.gg/twqjfnvxuwfv/0 in the ExampleModelDto I see the ModelContainer's ID instead of ExampleModel one. How to fix that?

Comment: I have also tried to exclude source ID, but there isn't such option in AutoMapper. Maybe you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @LambdaTheDev if you add `.ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Model.Id))` after the `IncludeMembers`, the `Id` of the `ExampleModel` is taken instead of the one from `ExampleModelContainer`. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/22psQP.